# API request to fetch users is not returning any data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Im trying to get all users and pass this down as a users prop to another component. Here is my users api slice.

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";

const usersAdapter = createEntityAdapter({});

const initialState = usersAdapter.getInitialState();

export const usersApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => "/users",
      validateStatus: (response, result) => {
        return response.status === 200 && !result.isError;
      },
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        const loadedUsers = responseData.map((user) => {
          user.id = user._id;
          return user;
        });
        return usersAdapter.setAll(initialState, loadedUsers);
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result?.ids) {
          return [
            { type: "User", id: "LIST" },
            ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: "User", id })),
          ];
        } else return [{ type: "User", id: "LIST" }];
      },
    }),
    addNewUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialUserData) => ({
        url: "/users",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          ...initialUserData,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: "User", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialUserData) => ({
        url: "/users",
        method: "PATCH",
        body: {
          ...initialUserData,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: "User", id: arg.id }],
    }),
    deleteUser: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        url: `/users`,
        method: "DELETE",
        body: { id },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: "User", id: arg.id }],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetUsersQuery,
  useAddNewUserMutation,
  useUpdateUserMutation,
  useDeleteUserMutation,
} = usersApiSlice;

// returns the query result object
export const selectUsersResult = usersApiSlice.endpoints.getUsers.select();

// creates memoized selector
const selectUsersData = createSelector(
  selectUsersResult,
  (usersResult) => usersResult.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
);

//getSelectors creates these selectors and we rename them with aliases using destructuring
export const {
  selectAll: selectAllUsers,
  selectById: selectUserById,
  selectIds: selectUserIds,
  // Pass in a selector that returns the users slice of state
} = usersAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => selectUsersData(state) ?? initialState
);
```

and here is where im trying to access this selectAllUsers get Selector.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAllUsers } from "../users/usersApiSlice";
import NewVehicleForm from "./NewVehicleForm";

const NewVehicle = () => {
  const users = useSelector(selectAllUsers);

  console.log(users);

  const content = users ? <NewVehicleForm users={users} /> : <p>Loading...</p>;

  return content;
};
export default NewVehicle;
```

when I run the app and the console.log runs it returns an empty array of users.

here is the component user is passed down to.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAddNewVehicleMutation } from "./vehiclesApiSlice";

const NewVehicleForm = ({ users }) => {
  const [addNewVehicle, { isLoading, isSuccess, isError, error }] =
    useAddNewVehicleMutation();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(users[0].id);
```

I have not put all of this file in as it is just one big form. I have put in the userId use state as when I run the app I get an error uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at NewVehicleForm (NewVehicleForm.js:11:1).

which further suggests that selectAllUsers is not working as intended.

I think I have set up my usersApiSlice wrong, specifically the get selectors.